# The type or namespace name 'FirebaseStorage' does not exist in the namespace 'FirebaseAdmin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, google-cloud-firestore, asp.net-core-webapi, firebase-admin

I was working on a sample project where I needed to upload an image of a user, I was using Firebase and the Storage from firebase also. But as soon as I installed the nuGet package "firebaseAdmin" I have been getting this error like the FirebaseStorage does not exist in the namespace FirebaseAdmin (are you missing an assemble reference?).

below is the complete error and the code where the error is coming from.

```
Severity : Error
Code : CS0234   
Description : The type or namespace name 'FirebaseStorage' does not exist in the namespace 'FirebaseAdmin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Project File : \employee_info1\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs
Line : 65
Suppression State : Active
```

I'm providing the foloowing snippet of code so that someone can help me out here

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Employee_id,username,password,dob,ImageFile")] Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Securely hash the password before storing
            string hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(employee.password, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt());
            employee.password = hashedPassword;

            // Upload image to Firebase Storage if provided
            if (employee.ImageFile != null)
            {
                var imageFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"; // Adjust filename extension if needed
                var storage = FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
                var reference = storage.GetReference($"images/{imageFilename}");
                await reference.PutAsync(employee.ImageFile.OpenReadStream());
                employee.ImageUrl = reference.GetDownloadUrl().ToString(); // Store image URL in employee model (optional)
            }

            // Store employee data in Firebase Realtime Database
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
            var data = employee;
            PushResponse response = client.Push("Employees/", data);
            data.Id = response.Result.name;
            SetResponse setResponse = client.Set("Employees/" + data.Id, data);

            if (setResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Employee Added Successfully");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Failed to add employee. Please try again.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            // Consider logging the error for debugging purposes
        }
    }

    return View(employee);
}
```

This is the line I'm having issues with,

```
var storage = FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
```

I already configured the firebase with authsecret and basepath.
I also used like

```
using FirebaseAdmin;
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using employee_info1.Models;
using FireSharp.Response;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using BCrypt.Net;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
```

I tried to see the reference manager and I found out that I don't have a filename that start with "Firebase" nor "FirebaseStorage".

I also tried to find(change) the .csproj file, and its no where to be found in the .Net 8.0.0.
below is the file I found when I clicked on the error.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <AssemblyBindingRedirects>
            <assemblyBinding assemblyName="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="keyToken" culture="neutral" oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
        </AssemblyBindingRedirects>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Next" Version="4.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FireSharp" Version="2.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.EntityFrameworkAdapter" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\NewFolder\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I asked help with ChatGPT and it shows to install "FirebaseAdmin.dll", I don't know where to find that file or how to resolve this specific issue. I have been trying to find a solution for almost 4 days.

**Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is  [Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/firebase-storage)

add the package:

```
<PackageReference Include="FirebaseStorage.net" Version="1.0.3" />
```

add the NameSpace:

```
using Firebase.Storage;
```

Comment: I installed the step-up-labs inc. "FirebaseStorage.net", nuGet Package Version=1.0.3. 

Should I then put this into the containing the ```<PackageReference>``` ?. 
When I added the name space it shows, ```var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;```, does not contain a definition for ```DefaultInstance```. What should i do?